# How to get the updated contents in a YUI simple editor from your view model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, yui

I am using `ASP.NET MVC3` with the `razor` view engine.  I am also using a the `Yahoo User Interface 2 (YUI2)` [simple editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/).

My view has a view model called `ProductEditViewModel`.  In this view model I have a property defined as:

```
public string LongDescription { get; set; }
```

In my view I would create the YUI2 simple editor from this input field.  The field is defined in the view like:

```
<td>@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.LongDescription, new { cols = "75", rows = "10" })<br>
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LongDescription)
</td>
```

Here is a partial view of my Edit action method:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit(ProductEditViewModel viewModel)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          // Check if valid
     }

     // I added this as a test to see what is returned
     string longDescription = viewModel.LongDescription;

     // Mapping
     Product product = new Product();
     product.InjectFrom(viewModel);

     // Update product in database
     productService.Update(product);

     return RedirectToRoute(Url.AdministrationProductIndex());
}
```

When I view the contents of the longDescription variable then it should contain the values from the editor.  If I edit the contents in the editor then longDescription still only contains the original contents, not the updated contents.  Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that somewhere in your POST action you have written something like this:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit(ProductEditViewModel viewModel)
{
     ...
     viewModel.LongDescription = "some new contents";
     return View(viewModel);
}
```

If this is the case then you should make sure that you have cleared the value from the ModelState before modifying it because HTML helpers will always first use the value from model state and then from the model.

So everytime you intend to manually modify some property of your view model inside a POST action make sure you remove it from modelstate:

```
ModelState.Remove("LongDescription");
viewModel.LongDescription = "some new contents";
return View(viewModel);
```

Now when the view is displayed, HTML helpers that depend on the `LongDescription` property will pick the new value instead of using the one that was initially submitted by the user.

Comment: I don't want to modify the contents of LongDescription in the action method.  I just want to retrieve it from the view model and write it directly to the database.

Comment: @BrendanVogt, then using `viewModel.LongDescription` you should be able to get the value that was POSTed. Verify with FireBug what value is exactly being sent when invoking this action.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is YUI that is preventing the update of the text to the view model, but the updated values was not showing in my view model when I post the form.  I tried out a jQuery plugin for a rich text editor, and it works perfectly.